# Ubuntu 17.10 failing to suspend on Dell XPS 9365

Tags: suspend, dell, 17.10

Closing the lid on Dell 9365 does not bring device in "suspend" mode: when re-opening the lid and logging, previous session is lost, with all applications abruptly terminated.

Comment: You could improve your question, there by getting better help, by including what you have done to try diagnosing or remedying the problem. - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/788148)

Comment: duplicate question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875024/dell-xps-13-9365-2-in-1-wont-resume-after-suspend-ubuntu-16-04